# send txt file in telegam via request website to telegram bot

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram-bot, sendfile

I want to send a file using a request website(https://www.httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx) and a bot in telegram
for example this code is for sending a massage in roobt :

```
TEXT = input('please enter your text : ')
url = (f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{apiToken}/sendmessage?chat_id={chatID}&text={TEXT}')
payload = {"UrlBox":url,
        "AgentList":"Mozilla Firefox",
        "VersionsList":"HTTP/1.1",
        "MethodList":"POST"
    }
req = requests.post("https://www.httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx" , data=payload)
print(req)
```

but i don't know how to send files with this website
i want to do this all because telegram is not working in our country and we have to use a vpn or third-party websites.

I tried chatgpt and searching in telegram documents
I found some guy named m7.arman (user:14770721) answered my question worng and it wasn't helpful
it is true and it works but it won't send file via https://www.httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply not possible to send files using that website.

Sending files using the [`sendDocument`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument) method requires passing the file as **multipart/form-data**, however, httpdebugger.com does not provide an optie to pass files as form-data for a POST request.

You'll need a proxy or an other website to send files to Telegram.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here on Stackoverflow. There are quite some questions on how to work around country blockages. If my answer helped you, please upvote/accept.

Comment: Can you please recommend a similar w-e-b - s-i-t-e ?

Comment: Please read my comment above, I cant, and if I could, I don't know any sites like that so I have no clue.

Comment: thnaks you so much